# TLS on Embedded Jetty without JKS

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, x509certificate, embedded-jetty

**My goal:** I am working on an integration of Jetty Embedded that would make it simple to use. The [interface](https://github.com/opsbears/owc-webserver/tree/master/src/main/java/com/opsbears/webcomponents/webserver) would allow, among others, for integration of external sources for TLS certificates, without the use of the Java KeyStore.

This would allow for greater flexibility when building distributed web services (in my case an [experimental, self-hosted CDN](https://pasztor.at/speaking/how-i-built-my-own-cdn-for-less-than-100-usd-vday-2017)).

However, I am having problems building the integration. The stub implementation is [in this repository](https://github.com/opsbears/owc-webserver-jetty/tree/master/src/main/java/com/opsbears/webcomponents/webserver/jetty).

**What I've tried:** I have tried replacing the [key manager](https://github.com/opsbears/owc-webserver-jetty/blob/master/src/main/java/com/opsbears/webcomponents/webserver/jetty/JettyX509ExtendedKeyManager.java) and the [trust manager](https://github.com/opsbears/owc-webserver-jetty/blob/master/src/main/java/com/opsbears/webcomponents/webserver/jetty/JettyX509TrustManager.java) and set break points to every function in it. However, when trying to access the server, these break points are never triggered. Instead, I'm encountering this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1478)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.fillRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$3.succeeded(SslConnection.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have tried analyzing the "standard" Jetty setup which a certificate from a keystore, but without much luck. I'm failing to find the point where Jetty is obtaining the cipher / certificate information that I should override.

**My question:** How can I get Jetty to use [my own certificate source](https://github.com/opsbears/owc-webserver/blob/master/src/main/java/com/opsbears/webcomponents/webserver/X509CertificateProvider.java) instead of the Java KeyStore and TrustStore?

Comment: This exception usually means the server couldn't find a private key and matching certificate. Clearly your `KeyManager` isn't installed correctly, or it would have been called prior to this.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to track down how the key manager is installed in the "stock" version vs. my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EJP pointed me in the right direction, so here's how to do it:

Here's how it needs to be done.

First, set up Jetty for TLS:

```
HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration();
https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new JettySslContextFactory(configuration.getSslProviders());
ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(
    server,
    new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"),
    new HttpConnectionFactory(https)
);
sslConnector.setPort(httpsPort);
```

Note the class JettySslContextFactory. This class extends the built-in X509ExtendedKeyManager and needs to override the `protected KeyManager[] getKeyManagers(KeyStore keyStore) throws Exception` method in order to provider a custom KeyManager, like this:

```
@Override
protected KeyManager[] getKeyManagers(KeyStore keyStore) throws Exception {
    return new KeyManager[] {
        new JettyX509ExtendedKeyManager(certificateProviders)
    };
}
```

In addition to that, the following steps are run in every connection:

1. The SNI matcher is consulted with the SNI host name. This seems to be the only place where the SNI host name is even available.
2. The key manager is consulted to get the alias (sort of a key ID) for a certain key type (EC or RSA). Here we need grab the host name from the SNI matcher, because otherwise we wouldn't know which host name to match on.
3. Based on the alias (key ID) we can then return the private key and certificate.

At least this is what I gathered from debugging this issue. The full code [is online here](https://github.com/opsbears/owc-webserver-jetty).